# How do I parse a JSON with Dictionary in it?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to parse a JSON and get the parameter value of "Name". And I  want to display the names of postal code areas in a label in table view cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ourCell") as! ourTableViewCell
    let temp = pinCodeData!["Post Office"][indexPath.row][0].dictionaryObject as! Dictionary<String,String>

    let temp2 = temp["Name"]
    print(temp)
    cell.ourLabel.text = temp2
    return cell
    }
let apiURL = "http://www.postalpincode.in/api/pincode/122001"
func ret(){
    Alamofire.request(apiURL, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                self.pinCodeData = JSON(response.result.value!)
                self.outTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you use `Codable` - Create appropriate structs to represent your JSON data and then you can access the required field easily

Comment: Your question is unclear. The second label is unclear, and it's unclear what `names of postal code areas` means. And already mentioned drop `SwiftyJSON` in favor of `Codable`. And declare the data source array `pinCodeData` as non-optional empty array.